# Connection between Classical and Quantum symmetries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, lie-algebra

I am an advanced undergraduate student.I would like to know about the importance of symmetry in classical and quantum mechanics.Also a good book concerning the connection between symmetries of classical and quantum mechanics which i can read at this level